# Devise a compact storage mode

Tags: numerics, homework

I am writing a code for solving a symmetric band matrix by Cholesky decomposition.  I need to store the matrix by defining only the non-zero diagonals of the matrix not the full matrix with band size $n$. How can one do that?

Comment: What about `SparseArray`?

Comment: I am not allowed to use it as my professor asked to create the code from blank!!

Comment: Then what about storing the diagonals of the matrix in conventional arrays?

Comment: I tried taking the Cholesky decomposition on a couple of symmetric band matrices, but it didn't work because they were not "sufficiently positive definite". Would be good to know some examples of band matrices one can experiment with.

Comment: Hilbert matrix of n=5 is trivial case of a band matrix

Comment: Henrik, this is what I am  trying to do, but I really don't know how!!

Comment: @strangeworld The Hilbert matrix was one of the matrices I experimented with. You can decompose it if it is a full matrix, but if you remove any bands then it can't be decomposed any longer. I thought maybe there would be something special about a banded symmetric matrix, different than just a symmetric matrix.